# onAfterRender plugin only triggers on backend

Tags: system-plugin, joomla-3.9

I have created a system plugin for onAfterRender event however I'm unable to make it execute. I'm on Joomla 3.9

Here's the sample code of the plugin

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2018 myvendorcustomscripts. All rights reserved.
     * @license     http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
     */
    -->
    <extension type="plugin" version="1.0" group="content" method="upgrade">
        <name>plg_system_myvendorcustomscripts</name>
        <author>myvendor</author>
        <creationDate>October 2018</creationDate>
        <copyright>Copyright (c) 2018 myvendorcustomscripts. All rights reserved.</copyright>
        <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL</license>
        <authorEmail></authorEmail>
        <authorUrl></authorUrl>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <description>
        <![CDATA[

        ]]>
        </description>

        <files>
            <filename plugin="myvendorcustomscripts">myvendorcustomscripts.php</filename>
            <filename>index.html</filename>
        </files>

        <languages>
            <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_system_myvendorcustomscripts.ini</language>
            <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_system_myvendorcustomscripts.sys.ini</language>
        </languages>

        <config>
            <fields name="params">
                <fieldset name="basic">

                </fieldset>
            </fields>
        </config>
    </extension>
```

And

```
        <?php
        /**
         * @copyright    Copyright (c) 2018 myvendorcustomscripts. All rights reserved.
         * @license        http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
         */

    // no direct access
        defined('_JEXEC') or die;

        jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

        /**
         * content - MyVendorCustomScripts Plugin
         *
         * @package        Joomla.Plugin
         * @subpakage    myvendorcustomscripts.MyVendorCustomScripts
         * @since
         */
        class plgSystemMyVendorCustomScripts extends JPlugin
        {
            /**
             * Constructor.
             *
             * @param    $subject
             * @param    array $config
             * @since
             */
            public function __construct(&$subject, $config = array())
            {
                // call parent constructor
                parent::__construct($subject, $config);
            }


            public function onAfterRender()
            {
                $app = JFactory::getApplication();

            }


            public function onBeforeCompileHead()
            {
                $app = JFactory::getApplication();
                $document = $app->getDocument();

                foreach ($document->_styleSheets as $index => $value) {
                    if (strpos($index, 'fonts.googleapis.com')) {
                        unset($document->_styleSheets[$index]);
                    }

                    if (strpos($index, 'simple-line-icons')) {
                        unset($document->_styleSheets[$index]);
                    }

    //                $styleSheet = $styleSheet;
                }
            }
        }
```

However the functions never get executed when I'm browsing the frontend but they do get executed when browsing the backend. It's really strange and I can't understand the reason. It seems on the documentation that this even should trigger always

Comment: Are you using any sort of caching? System - Page Cache plugin or similar can be causing this.

Comment: Well, $document->_styleSheets doesn't execute in the frontend. Do you need the data from the backend?  I've been using System - Page Cache yes, and indeed it's the reason that it's not breaking. As soon as I completely disabled it, my breakpoint was hit. So what can I do to fix this? Caching is really important to completely disable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you currently have works. You just need to clear page cache and view the page again. You'll see `fonts.googleapis.com` links are removed. This may or may not be fine depending on the rest of your code.

When System - Page Cache plugin is enabled, on first load page (determined by URL) on is rendered normally with all expected plugin events triggered and stored to cache during `onAfterRespond` event. On following page loads the plugin fetches the page from cache, pushes it to application and closes the application. This happens during `onAfterInitialise` event. No further events are triggered. Except `onAfterRespond` if debug is enabled.

The code you currently have in `onBeforeCompileHead` actually works fine because your changes are applied before the page is stored to cache.

However, in case you want to add code that is not cache-safe, e.g. code that changes from visitor to visitor or some randomly generated code, you could selectively disable cache using `onPageCacheSetCaching` event.

Comment: OK I see, this was very informative. Thank you very much. So even if I enable the system plugin `Page Cache` this will execute when I clear the cache completely, only once for each page. Then the saved page will be served ignoring all events. In my case I don't wish to disable caching for specific pages as this will go site-wide but I want some specific DOM Manipulation to occur to clear some Pagespeed Insights issues before serving the page.